# fast string modification in python

Tags: python, string

This is partially a theoretical question:

I have a string (say UTF-8), and I need to modify it so that each character (not byte) becomes 2 characters, for instance:

```
"Nissim" becomes "N-i-s-s-i-m-"


"01234" becomes "0a1b2c3d4e"
```

and so on.
I would suspect that naive concatenation in a loop would be too expensive (it IS the bottleneck, this is supposed to happen all the time).

I would either use an array (pre-allocated) or try to make my own C module to handle this.

Anyone has better ideas for this kind of thing?

(Note that the problem is always about multibyte encodings, and must be solved for UTF-8 as well),

Oh and its Python 2.5, so no shiny Python 3 thingies are available here.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "too expensive"? How expensive have you found the naïve approach to be?

Comment: Never benchmarked it, but I suspect that memory will be allocated, freed and reallocated again, N times for N chars in the input.

Comment: Profile it now. Python optimizes string manipulating. Don't _ever_ assume something to be too expensive if not profiled.

Comment: @gnosis - Bear in mind that with a generational garbage collector such as Python's, allocating and deallocating short-lived objects is actually pretty fast.  Assumptions in this area can be dangerous.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@gnosis, beware of all the well-intentioned responders saying you should measure the times: yes, you should (because programmers' instincts are often off-base about performance), **but** measuring a single case, as in all the `timeit` examples proffered so far, misses a crucial consideration -- **big-O**.

Your instincts are correct: *in general* (with a very few special cases where recent Python releases can optimize things a bit, but they don't stretch very far), building a string by a loop of `+=` over the pieces (or a `reduce` and so on) must be `O(N**2)` due to the many intermediate object allocations and the inevitable repeated copying of those object's content; joining, regular expressions, and the third option that was not mentioned in the above answers (`write` method of `cStringIO.StringIO` instances) are the `O(N)` solutions and therefore the only ones worth considering unless you happen to **know** for sure that the strings you'll be operating on have modest upper bounds on their length.

So what, if any, are the upper bounds in length on the strings you're processing? If you can give us an idea, benchmarks can be run on *representative* ranges of lengths of interest (for example, say, "most often less than 100 characters but some % of the time maybe a couple thousand characters" would be an excellent spec for this performance evaluation: IOW, it doesn't need to be extremely precise, just indicative of your problem space).

I also notice that nobody seems to follow one crucial and difficult point in your specs: that the strings are Python 2.5 multibyte, UTF-8 encoded, `str`s, and the insertions must happen only after each "complete character", *not* after each *byte*. Everybody seems to be "looping on the str", which give each byte, not each *character* as you so clearly specify.

There's really no good, fast way to "loop over characters" in a multibyte-encoded byte `str`; the best one can do is to `.decode('utf-8')`, giving a unicode object -- process the unicode object (where loops *do* correctly go over characters!), then `.encode` it back at the end. By far the best approach in general is to only, exclusively use unicode objects, **not** encoded `str`s, throughout the heart of your code; encode and decode to/from byte strings only upon I/O (if and when you must because you need to communicate with subsystems that only support byte strings and not proper Unicode).

So I would strongly suggest that you consider this "best approach" and restructure your code accordingly: unicode everywhere, except at the boundaries where it may be encoded/decoded if and when necessary only. For the "processing" part, you'll be MUCH happier with unicode objects than you would be lugging around balky multibyte-encoded strings!-)

**Edit**: forgot to comment on a possible approach you mention -- `array.array`. That's indeed O(N) *if* you are only *appending* to the end of the new array you're constructing (some appends will make the array grow beyond previously allocated capacity and therefore require a reallocation and copying of data, **but**, just like for list, a midly exponential overallocation strategy allows `append` to be *amortized* O(1), and therefore N appends to be O(N)).

However, to build an array (again, just like a list) by repeated `insert` operations in the middle of it is `O(N**2)`, because each of the O(N) insertions must shift all the O(N) following items (assuming the number of previously existing items and the number of newly inserted ones are proportional to each other, as seems to be the case for your specific requirements).

So, an `array.array('u')`, with repeated `append`s to it (**not** `insert`s!-), is a fourth O(N) approach that can solve your problem (in addition to the three I already mentioned: `join`, `re`, and `cStringIO`) -- *those* are the ones worth benchmarking once you clarify the ranges of lengths that are of interest, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Alex, great response! Considering the array.array approach - it should only have one allocation total since I know how many chars I am going to have at output. So far I am going to test this one plus re and zip - the zip might give python a chance to properly treat the allocation and breakdown of the input. Will post results.

Comment: @gnosis, making the array once (e.g. fill it w/'-'s if that's the char you need to append to every other char) then assigning to some of its items is promising. But what's the length distribution of strings of interest to you?

Comment: @alex-martelli, the length distribution is pretty much what you guessed - I'd say most of the time (like 80%) below 200 chars. Why does the filling matter? I would just allocate the memory once and then fill the data in by simple assignment. If I could allow output to be UTF-16 it could be a blast...

Comment: @gnosis, there is no "allocating" an array without filling it with something. So you might as well fill it with the right character(s) from the start, e.g. `x=array.array('U', (2*len(s))*'-')` to allocate it filled with dashes, then `x[::2]=array.array('U', x)`, this should probably be the fastest approach (or other slice assignments if you're requiring something slightly different). You do need unicode internally, but a final .encode('utf-8') shouldn't slow you down too much (and neither should the initial .decode upon input).

Answer (score 2):

Try to build the result with the [`re` module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html). It will do the nasty concatenation under the hood, so performance should be OK. Example:

```
 import re
 re.sub(r'(.)', r'\1-', u'Nissim')

 count = 1
 def repl(m):
     global count
     s = m.group(1) + unicode(count)
     count += 1
     return s
 re.sub(r'(.)', repl, u'Nissim')
```

Comment: I haven't tested but I think re module will give least performance and is overkill here

Comment: Since you didn't test, there is a 90% chance that you're wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

this might be a python effective solution:

```
s1="Nissim"
s2="------"
s3=''.join([''.join(list(x)) for x in zip(s1,s2)])
```

Comment: Reduntant whole list creations will slow it down. Drop the [] just inside the outer .join(), and take in itertools.izip instead of zip.

Comment: `''.join(i+j for i, j in zip(s1, s2))` would be enough

Comment: @SlientHost: actually you solution is slower see my answer

Comment: @kaizer.se - That's a suggestion that's worth profiling or timing.  Bear in mind that zip is a built-in function and is therefore faster to call than izip.  I don't know which is likely to be faster, but I know not to trust my instincts in this area.  :-)

Comment: I don't see where you tested *my* solution, Anurag

Comment: @SlientGhost: sorry see now, my comp hanged ;)

Answer (score 1):

have you tested how slow it is or how fast you need, i think something like this will be fast enough

```
s = u"\u0960\u0961"
ss = ''.join(sum(map(list,zip(s,"anurag")),[]))
```

So try with simplest and if it doesn't suffice then try to improve upon it, C module should be last option

**Edit:** This is also the fastest

```
import timeit

s1="Nissim"
s2="------"

timeit.f1=lambda s1,s2:''.join(sum(map(list,zip(s1,s2)),[]))
timeit.f2=lambda s1,s2:''.join([''.join(list(x)) for x in zip(s1,s2)])
timeit.f3=lambda s1,s2:''.join(i+j for i, j in zip(s1, s2))

N=100000

print "anurag",timeit.Timer("timeit.f1('Nissim', '------')","import timeit").timeit(N)
print "dweeves",timeit.Timer("timeit.f2('Nissim', '------')","import timeit").timeit(N)
print "SilentGhost",timeit.Timer("timeit.f3('Nissim', '------')","import timeit").timeit(N)
```

output is

```
anurag 1.95547590546
dweeves 2.36131184271
SilentGhost 3.10855625505
```

Comment: it's not fair comparison at all, have a look at my suggestion on how to improve that answer. and it'll be twice faster than yours.

Comment: @SlientGhost I have added your solution and it is slowest

Comment: hmmm is it differnce between py2.5 and py3 or style of testing?

Comment: I've tested first your way, and my results don't change

Comment: I guess SilentGhost solution is the fastest:
anurag 0.775900713444
dweeves 0.740725330615
SilentGhost 0.599001875506

I have Python 2.6 on windows

Answer (score 1):

here are my timings. Note, it's py3.1

```
>>> s1
'Nissim'
>>> s2 = '-' * len(s1)
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(i+j for i, j in zip(s1, s2))", "from __main__ import s1, s2")
3.5249209707199043
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(sum(map(list,zip(s1,s2)),[]))", "from __main__ import s1, s2")
5.903614027402
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join([''.join(list(x)) for x in zip(s1,s2)])", "from __main__ import s1, s2")
6.04072124013328
>>> timeit.timeit("''.join(i+'-' for i in s1)", "from __main__ import s1, s2")
2.484378367653335
>>> timeit.timeit("reduce(lambda x, y : x+y+'-', s1, '')", "from __main__ import s1; from functools import reduce")
2.290644129319844
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Reduce.

```
>>> str = "Nissim"
>>> reduce(lambda x, y : x+y+'-', str, '')
'N-i-s-s-i-m-'
```

The same with numbers too as long as you know which char maps to which. [dict can be handy]

```
>>> mapper = dict([(repr(i), chr(i+ord('a'))) for i in range(9)])
>>> str1 = '0123'
>>> reduce(lambda x, y : x+y+mapper[y], str1, '')
'0a1b2c3d'
```

Comment: I'd have to see numbers to believe that this is a fast solution.  The overhead of a function call in Python can actually be pretty high.

Comment: @Jason: curiously enough, reduce is faster so far

Answer (score 0):

```
string="™¡™©€"
unicode(string,"utf-8")
s2='-'*len(s1)
''.join(sum(map(list,zip(s1,s2)),[])).encode("utf-8")
```